# How to handle authentication tokens in MEAN stack application

Tags: mean-stack, auth-token

I am a newbie to MEAN stack and developing an end-to-end application using MEAN. I have a small confusion on how to handle authentication tokens on client side (i.e. in Angularjs).

I created an authentication token after either the user signup's or login to the application. I followed [this link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/token-based-authentication-with-angularjs-nodejs--cms-22543) for creating authentication token. I set the authentication token in response headers and saving it on the browsers localStorage on client side. I accessed it whenever i did a REST call.

Is it a good practice to access tokens directly from the localStorage or i need to access the token by creating either a factory or a service ?. I have seen many SO answers, in which they access the tokens by creating either a factory or a service, but my confusion is if i can able to access the token straight away from localStorage why i need to create a factory or service ? Is there any best practices for it ?

Comment: to much words - no code, no charts)

Comment: My doubt was , is it a good practice to access the tokens directly using ,

`$window.localStorage.getItem('tokenName');` (or) should i use a service to do that like
` app.factory('getTokens' function(){
         return {
             // code to access browsers local strage .
         }
  }):` 

??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MEAN.IO` provide methodology of [Test-Driving-Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) and has several Karma test cases from the box. For unit testing you should to write factory `app.factory('getTokens)` and then write test case for it like:

- User Logged In -> Ok.
- User Not Logged In -> **Throw Error.**

But If you, for some reason, does not support TDD - you shouldn't.